# Making containers use host's proxy on MacOS

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm running Docker Desktop for MacOS.  Like many of us, I'm working from home right now and I access certain services that are inside the corporate firewall from my home machine via a SOCKS5 proxy. I'm trying to build a number of services in Docker containers and these containers also need access to the services at work.  The problem is that Docker on MacOS does not support SOCKS proxies. I was hoping I could use something like host network mode, but that is also not supported on MacOS.

Any suggestions on how I do the above (other than switching to Linux ;-))

**EDIT: add more detail on my environment.**

- Working from home on a Mac running MacOS Catalina Connected to
  various services at work using SOCKS5 proxy and a few SSH tunnels.
- Running the Proxifier application to make it easier to allow variousapplications to tunnel via the SOCKS proxy.
- Docker Desktop for MacOS.
- Ruby on Rails stack inside a Docker container in which certain Gems are developed in-house and
  hosted on our internal (behind the corporate firewall) Gitlab server. So the stack needs access to that Gitlab server when the Gems are installed.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I think I've come up with something workable. I'd still appreciate comments on this in case there's a better way. I'm always happy to learn.

- Proxifier routes all traffic to *.mydomain.com to the SOCKS5 proxy.
- I've created an SSH tunnel on my MacOS host: `-L 8443:gitlab-server.mydomain.com:443`
- In the Gemfile, I reference the gitlab server as `https://host.docker.internal:8443`

The only sticky bit was that I get an SSL cert verification error since I'm not referencing the Gitlab server at the *.mydomain.com domain.  I worked around this by doing `git config --global http.sslVerify "false"` just before the bundle install so that the git clone commands issued by the Bundler to install the Gitlab-hosted Gems ignore SSL verification errors.

This seems to be working fairly well. The actual Gitlab URL in the Gemfile is parameterized so that the "real" Gitlab URL can be used when inside the corporate firewall.